# Error: Can't resolve 'react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css'

Tags: react-spinners

I am trying to use react-loader-spinner package in my current project [Here is the package](https://github.com/mhnpd/react-loader-spinner), but it shows me an error.
When I imported (`import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";`) in the main app.js the error showed in vs code.
I also followed the documentation nothing worked for me.
I attached the picture of the error
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhykR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem as I installed the package as follows: `npm install react-loader-spinner --save`. I think there was some package version limitation. Try to install the package with the version below:
`npm install react-loader-spinner@4.0.0 --save` I presume this will resolve above error.